# Scraping multiple pages with beautifulsoup4 using python 3.6.3

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I am trying to loop through multiple pages and my code doesn't extract anything. I am kind of new to scraping so bear with me. I made a container so I can target each listing. I also made a variable to target the anchor tag that you would press to go to the next page. I would really appreciate any help I could get. Thanks.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

for page in range(0,25):
    file = "breakfeast_chicago.csv"
    f = open(file, "w")
    Headers = "Nambusiness_name, business_address, business_city, business_region, business_phone_number\n"
f.write(Headers)

my_url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Stores&geo_location_terms=Chicago%2C%20IL&page={}'.format(page)

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()   

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# grabs each listing
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class": "result"})

new = page_soup.findAll("a", {"class":"next ajax-page"})

for i in new:
    try:
        for container in containers:
            b_name = i.find("container.h2.span.text").get_text()
            b_addr = i.find("container.p.span.text").get_text()

            city_container = container.findAll("span",{"class": "locality"})
            b_city = i.find("city_container[0].text ").get_text()

            region_container = container.findAll("span",{"itemprop": "postalCode"})
            b_reg = i.find("region_container[0].text").get_text()

            phone_container = container.findAll("div",{"itemprop": "telephone"})
            b_phone = i.find("phone_container[0].text").get_text()

            print(b_name, b_addr, b_city, b_reg, b_phone)
            f.write(b_name + "," +b_addr + "," +b_city.replace(",", "|") + "," +b_reg + "," +b_phone + "\n")
    except: AttributeError
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like the below script. It will traverse different pages through pagination and collect name and phone numbers from each container.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Stores&geo_location_terms=Chicago%2C%20IL&page={}"
for link in [my_url.format(page) for page in range(1,5)]:
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

    for item in soup.select(".info"):
        try:
            name = item.select(".business-name [itemprop='name']")[0].text
        except Exception:
            name = ""
        try:
            phone = item.select("[itemprop='telephone']")[0].text
        except Exception:
            phone = ""

        print(name,phone)
```

Comment: Thanks! i gave it a try and it didn't work at first but i changed "lxml" to "html.parser" and it worked. Is there any reason "lxml" didn't work?

Comment: Strange!! I don't find any reason for that. They both works alternatively. Btw, be sure to accept it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If using BS4 try : `find_all`

Try dropping into a trace using `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` and try to debug what is being selected in the for loop.

Also, some content may be hidden if it is loaded via javascript.

Each anchor tag or href for "clicking" is just another network request, and if you plan to follow the link consider slowing down the number of requests in between each request, so you don't get blocked.

Comment: ok thanks. from what i understand bs4 just works with html and xml. is there any other library you would recommend that might be more useful in the situation where content is hidden?

Comment: @luisreyes if you need to load extra hidden content via javascript then you can try selenium, or headless chrome, or maybe even phantomjs.